# Where are appsettings after compiled in a dotnet core 2.1

Tags: .net-core, appsettings

I am trying to understand how the `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.{Environment}.json` and the environment variables play along in a dotnet core 2.1 application but I don't know how at runtime the appsettings (whatever the final transformation is) are accessed by the application.

I would expect to have the appsettings among the compiled dll (e.g: `MyWebApiApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1`), but I don't see it there.

Understanding this would help me find out the best approach for OpenShift configmaps vs appsettings, because I need to know whether I should rely on appsettings at runtime or whether appsettings is something useful for development but on production I should rely on environment variables rather.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the code from within Visual Studio? The default `CreateDefaultBuilder` uses the `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` to determine which folder to load the settings files from. When you are running from within Visual Studio the current directory is your project directory - so when you run/debug the program it finds the correct settings file.

One way to test this is to change to a command line and run your applications using `dotnet myapp.dll`. If you are loading settings from an `appsettings` file it will not find the file and the settings will be null.

If you change the properties on your `appsettings` file to `copy if newer` and rebuild your app, when you run it from the command line it will correctly find the settings file.

You can take a look at the how the webhost determines which settings to use by looking at the [implementation file](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L148). But, in short, dotnetcore will use settings in the following order:

- appsettings.json
- environment variables
- command line

The documentation for this is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1#set-up-a-host)

So, if there are settings that could change once the app is deployed then you can overwrite them via environment variables. You could redeploy the `appsettings` files if you want to configure that way but, from my experience, it is much easier to handle production settings via environment variables, possibly using a third party tool e.g. puppet.

Hope that helps.